# Is this an incorrect use of intrinsic condition queue in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

This program attempts to print numbers 1 to 10 in a sequential manner, 1 thread prints odd numbers and the second threads prints even numbers.

I have been reading JCIP book and it says:

> Ensure that the state variables making up the condition predicate are guarded by the lock associated with the condition queue.

In the below program, the condition queue will correspond to static member 'obj1' while the state variable that makes up the condition predicate is static volatile member 'count'. *(let me know if I am wrong in the interpretation of condition, state variable, condition predicate)*

The below program works correctly but is clearly violating the above idiom. Have I understood what the author is trying to say correctly? Is the below code really a poor programming practice (which happens to work correctly)

Can you give me an example where not following the above idiom will make me run into problems?

```
public class OddEvenSynchronized implements Runnable {
    static Object obj1 = new Object();         // monitor to share data
    static volatile int count =1;              // condition predicate
    boolean isEven; 
    public OddEvenSynchronized(boolean isEven) {   //constructor
        this.isEven=isEven;
    }
    public void run (){
        while (count<=10){
            if (this.isEven == true){
                printEven();                   //print an even number
            }
            else{
                printOdd();                     //print an odd number
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new  OddEvenSynchronized(true));
        Thread t2 = new Thread (new  OddEvenSynchronized(false));
        //start the 2 threads
        t1.start();       
        t2.start();
    }

    void printEven(){
        synchronized (obj1) {
            while (count%2 != 0){
                try{
                    obj1.wait();
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even"+count);      

        count++;  //unguarded increment (violation)
        synchronized (obj1) {
            obj1.notifyAll();
        }
    }                            //end method
    void printOdd(){
        synchronized (obj1) {
            while (count%2 == 0){
                try{
                    obj1.wait();
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Odd"+count);
        count++;     //unguarded increment (violation)
        synchronized (obj1) {
            obj1.notifyAll();
        }

    }                          //end method
}   //end class
```

Comment: There is no 'intrinsic condition queue'. There are only intrinsic locks, with no queue. That's why you have to have a condition variable and an acquisition loop.

Comment: can you explain? JCIP says every object has an intrinsic lock and an intrinsic condition queue.

Comment: The quotation you cited doesn't say that. It says 'condition queue', not 'intrinsic condition queue'. More context is required but I suspect the code itself is implementing a condition queue. Or else the book is wrong. If there was a condition queue associated with the lock you wouldn't need an extra variable or the acquisition loop.

Comment: to quote from the book, "An object's intrinsic lock and its intrinsic condition queue are related: ..." pg. 297

Comment: I have the book somewhere but I can't check it until Monday. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: NB Don't compare Boolean expressions to true or false. They already are true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I have been able to come up with for this question, as hinted by my discussion with John Kugelman in his answer (please correct if something is wrong):

**1st Key insight:** In Java, there is only one condition queue associated with the object's monitor. And although they share the condition queue, there condition predicates are different. This sharing results in unnecessary wakeup ->check condition predicate -> sleep again. So although inefficient, they will still behave as kind of separate condition queues if coded properly ( while ( condition predicate ) { thread.wait() } )

In the above program, the condition predicates

1. count%2 == 0
2. count%2 != 0

are different, although they are part of the same condition queue (i.e. doing a notify() on this object's monitor will wake both of them, however only one would be able to proceed at a time).

**The 2nd key insight:** 
The volatile count variable ensure memory visibility.

**Conclusion:**

As soon as we introduce another thread with the same condition predicate, the program will be susceptible to race conditions (if not other defects).

Also, note that usually wait() notify() mechanism is employed for object with same condition predicated, for example, waiting for a resource lock. The above program is usually used in interviews and I doubt if it would be common in real-life code.

So, if there are two or more threads in the same condition queue with different condition predicates, and the condition predicate variable is volatile (and hence ensures memory visibility), then ignoring the above advice can produce a correct program. Although this is of little significance, this really helped me understand multi-threading better.

Comment: If there was a queue there wouldn't *be* an 'unnecessary wakeup ->check condition predicate -> sleep again'. I don't have that book as it turns out, but the book you're citing is wrong to the point of nonsense.

Comment: I don't agree. There must be one condition queue, (book or not), otherwise where will the threads wait?  The book is written by Brian Gotze.

Answer (score 1):

Do not read from or write to `count` if you're not synchronized on `obj1`. That's a no no! The prints and the increments should be done from inside synchronized blocks.

```
synchronized (obj1) {
    while (count%2 != 0){
        try {
            obj1.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Even"+count);      
}

synchronized (obj1) {
    count++;
    obj1.notifyAll();
}
```

You'll notice that there's no reason to drop the synchronization now. Combine the two blocks.

```
synchronized (obj1) {
    while (count%2 != 0){
        try {
            obj1.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Even"+count);      
    count++;
    obj1.notifyAll();
}
```

> The below program works correctly but is clearly violating the above idiom.

The insidious danger of multithreaded programming is that a buggy program can *appear* to work correctly most of the time. Race conditions can be quite devious because they often require very tight timing conditions which rarely happen.

It's really, really important to follow the rules to the letter. It's very difficult to get multithreaded programming right. It's a near certainty that any time you deviate from the rules and try to be clever you will introduce subtle bugs.

Comment: Why exactly is it a no-no? that's what I am trying to find out. If you look closely, count is volatile, so there is no need to put it in synchronized. I explicitly made this program the way it is.

Comment: Response to your edit: so what is the race condition that will break the program in this case?

Comment: Your program may be okay with just the two threads. I haven't spotted any flaws as is, not yet at least. But you'll have problems if you introduce more threads. Keeping `synchronized` active ensures that `count` doesn't change after the `while` loop ends and the subsequent printout, or after the printout and before the increment.

Comment: It's really, really important to follow the rules to the letter. 
No, it's more important to understand the rules first, before following them,

Comment: Imagine you run an additional "even" thread. With proper synchronization, that would be okay and the observable behavior would be the same. The two even threads would fight each other and only one would win each time, and that'd be fine. With your program as is, though, I can imagine all kinds of race conditions. Both threads might simultaneously detect and print the even numbers, for instance. Is that the kind of response you're looking for? If so, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: In case of additional even thread, my program can print even number twice due to the race condition, in that case count++ should be synchronized. But the resultant program isn't still following the JCIP idiom.

Comment: Synchronizing just `count++` isn't sufficient. Thread A checks `count%2`, sees that it's even, and makes it through the first synchronized block. Before it can print anything, Thread B runs and does the same thing. That causes them both to print "Even".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88235/discussion-between-john-kugelman-and-rents).